# Sitecore Form custom error message is not displaying for Email Validator

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a form in my page. One of the requirements is to validate the email address if it is valid or not.

I put my custom error message from  `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations/Email Validator`, then published.

Upon testing it, it did not display the custom error message. I conducted my investigation and I found out that the error message that was being displayed is coming from `jquery.validate.min.js` which is located inside the webroot `\wwwroot\Site\sitecore modules\Web\ExperienceForms\scripts`.

There is an easy hack about it and that is to change the text inside the js but I know for sure that it will eventually be a problem once the language versioning happened.

Can somebody from this group help me how to solve this?

Please note: This is Sitecore Forms and not WFFM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing the message in "/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations/Email Validator" should work for you. You might want to verify in the web database to make sure the Email Validator item was indeed published.

Comment: I did change the message from that file and I even checked the web database about it. I just used the default regex expression.